# isappendChild() a function for an anodeList

Tags: javascript, appendchild

```
const cardSet = ['fa-diamond','fa-diamond','fa-paper-plane-o','fa-paper- 
plane-o','fa-anchor','fa-anchor','fa-bolt','fa-bolt','fa-cube','fa-cube','fa- 
leaf','fa-leaf','fa-bicycle','fa-bicycle','fa-bomb','fa-bomb'];
let cardsOpen=[];
let cardsflipped = 0;
let theDeck= document.getElementsByClassName('deck');


 window.onload=function startGame(){
shuffle(cardSet);
let cards;
cardSet.forEach(function (){
    cards= document.createElement('li');
    cards.classList.add('card')
    cards.innerHTML='<i class="fa '+ cardSet +'"></i>';
});
theDeck.appendChild(cards);
};
```

Hello! I have been trying to create a memory game.
This function initiate the game.
But everytime I run the code an error occurs saying appendChild(cards) is not a function.
can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let theDeck= document.getElementsByClassName('deck');`

creates a node list and `.appendChild()` is not a method of node lists, it's a method of a single node. You'll need to reference a single, specific node and call `.appendChild()` on that.